# msdeploy error ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED: Web deployment task failed

Tags: msbuild, tfs-2015, msdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

Web deployment task failed. Error ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED

We are using Tfs Build Automation and msdeploy for publishing an web application on remote machine.

On "Visual Studio Build" step we set this parameters on "MSBuild Arguments": 
/p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=myProfile;AllowUntrustedCertificate=true;UserName=$(UserName);Password=$(Password)

After quing the build we get this error:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4276,5): Error ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED: Web deployment task failed. (Connected to the remote computer ("MySERVER") using the Web Management Service, but could not authorize. Make sure that you are using the correct user name and password, that the site you are connecting to exists, and that the credentials represent a user who has permissions to access the site. Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.)

I am sure that username and password is correct, and the user isAdministrator on the server (MySERVER).

I checked the Management Service log on IIS and found something important:
the build agent's username(tfsadmin) sent for deploy on IIS instead of the user/pass that I set in build variables.

## Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken

2018-01-03 09:29:02 MYSERVERIP HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=MySiteName 8172 - MyBuildServerIP - - 401 2 5 1322
2018-01-03 09:29:02 MYSERVERIP HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=MySiteName 8172 tfsadmin MyBuildServerIP - - 401 1 1326 86

**Update 1:** 
I add more information, as you see below in build log, in msBuildArgs the password is empty (instead of ********)!

WebDeploy Version : 3.6
TFS Version : 2015.1
Target Machine (MySERVER) : Windows 2012 R2
IIS Version : 8.5
The "tfsadmin" user has local administrator of target server (MyServer) and IIS Manager Permission on the target IIS Site.

**Build log :**

> ```
> 2018-01-06T06:37:19.9298797Z Starting task: Build solution $/MyProject/MySolution.sln
> 2018-01-06T06:37:20.0529203Z Executing the powershell script: D:\Agents\Agent-01\tasks\VSBuild\1.0.16\VSBuild.ps1
> 2018-01-06T06:37:20.3760645Z ##[debug]Entering script VSBuild.ps1
> 2018-01-06T06:37:20.3790648Z ##[debug]vsLocation = 
> 2018-01-06T06:37:20.3800653Z ##[debug]vsVersion = 14.0
> 2018-01-06T06:37:20.3810663Z ##[debug]msBuildLocation = 
> 2018-01-06T06:37:20.3820668Z ##[debug]msBuildVersion = 
> 2018-01-06T06:37:20.3830692Z ##[debug]msBuildArchitecture = x64
> 2018-01-06T06:37:20.3840679Z ##[debug]msBuildArgs = /p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=myProfile;AllowUntrustedCertificate=true;UserName=tfsadmin;Password=;Pass2=********
> 2018-01-06T06:37:20.3840679Z ##[debug]solution = D:\Agents\Agent-01\_work\2\s\MyProject\MySolution.sln
> 2018-01-06T06:37:20.3860721Z ##[debug]platform = 
> 2018-01-06T06:37:20.3870700Z ##[debug]configuration = 
> 2018-01-06T06:37:20.3880727Z ##[debug]clean = true
> 2018-01-06T06:37:20.3890697Z ##[debug]restoreNugetPackages = true
> 2018-01-06T06:37:20.3890697Z ##[debug]logProjectEvents = true
> 2018-01-06T06:37:20.4010877Z ##[debug]Loading module from path 'D:\Agents\Agent-01\agent\worker\Modules\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.dll'.
> ...
> ```

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Can you deploy the web app successfully with the MSBuild Arguments you set from the command line in your develop machine?

Comment: Yes, I can deploy from MSBuild in dev machine

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the wrong username and password were ultimately used to authenticate the request. Running the command `net helpmsg 1326` (1326 is the `sc-win32-status` value from the log entry you provided) yields "*The user name or password is incorrect.*"

Also interesting is the request/response logged before that. The substatus value 2 for a 401 means "*Access is denied due to server configuration favoring an alternate authentication method.*" according to [TechNet](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/c9511f97-d898-4aed-b0a8-979ce30d85b5.mspx?mfr=true). And `net helpmsg 1322` yields "*This operation is disallowed as it could result in an administration account being disabled, deleted or unable to logon.*"

1. Review (or re-review) the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-web-deploy/configure-the-web-deployment-handler
2. If your deployment is still not working, take a look at [Microsoft's *Troubleshooting Common Problems with Web Deploy*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/troubleshooting-common-problems-with-web-deploy).

Comment: Thanks weir, I khnow what the error said, but my problem is why it use the username/password of build-agent-service instead of the one that I set on build variable

Answer (score 1):

Deploy from VS with the command line will use the user name and password you provided. However deploy from TFS will use the build agent. So, the first thing is that the service account of the build process should has the correct permission to access the remote server.

Just try to give the build **service account** `local administrator` permissions and *`IIS Manager Permissionson`* to the site's scope on the remote server ("MySERVER"). Then set the username parameter to `""`  (empty quotes) and the password field omitted.

Reference: [Build only works with username and password in msbuild arguments](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f552c8d7-e7dc-4e04-8cf7-f5fa7461f3e8/build-only-works-with-username-and-password-in-msbuild-arguments?forum=tfsgeneral)

> This error code can surface because of a number of different reasons.
>   It typically indicates an authentication or authorization problem, and
>   can happen because of any of hte following reasons:
>
> If connecting using the Web Management Service:
>
> - Verify that the username and password are correct
> - Verify that the site exists
> - Verify that the user has IIS Manager Permissions to the site's    scope
>
> If connecting using the Remote Agent Service:
>
> - Verify that the username and password are correct
> - **Verify that the user account you specified is a member of the    Administrators group on the remote computer. NOTE: Because of a bug
>
>     in Web Deploy 2.0, the user must be either the built-in Administrator 
>     or a member of the Domain Administrators security group. Attempts to
>
>     sync with any other user account, even if it is an administrator,
>
>     will see this error code. Verify that the site exists**

Reference : [ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes#erroruserunauthorized)

---

**UPDATE:**

By default, Web Deploy will connect using HTTP Basic Authentication.
When using HTTP Basic Authentication, specific credentials must be supplied, 
e.g.

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:dump -source:apphostconfig,wmsvc=demo-host,authType:basic,username=someuser,password=somepassword
```

In your scenario, you can try set the `AuthType` as `NTLM`, then try it again.

Just try adding the line `<AuthType>NTLM</AuthType>` to the publish `.pubxml` file.

Comment: Thanks Andy, the service account (tfsadmin) has local administrator permission on remote machine (MyServer) and IIS Manage Permission on target Site. I set the Username parameter to "" and the problem exists but with new error :  Web deployment task failed. (The specified credentials cannot be used with the authentication scheme 'Basic'.)
The specified credentials cannot be used with the authentication scheme 'Basic'.
Default credentials cannot be supplied for the Basic authentication scheme.
Parameter name: authType

Comment: @OmidShariati Just try adding the following line to .pubxml file.

  `<AuthType>NTLM</AuthType>`. See the updated answer.

Comment: @OmidShariati Have you resolved the issue? any update?

Comment: Thanks @andy-li-msft our target environments has changed during this das and I can't test this issue again.The target environment was not on the same domain as our build/tfs server that has this issue. in a few weeks later we can test it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- On your server go to Computer Management
- From the left pan select Local Users and Groups
- Go to users find the `tfsadmin` user
- Right click on it and click on Set Password
- Give your existing password (whatever it is)

This seems unnecessary but worked for me. I hope someone can explain the "why".